# Conditional logic based off of what a user searched?

Tags: magento-1.9, search, catalogsearch

Let me try and explain what I mean.

We have one product SKU: ABC123

It fits two different models(a set variable): XX22 & XX23

XX22 is an apple(category) product

XX23 is a samsung(category) product

If someone searches XX23 it will show the product: ABC123. I want a way for it to show that it's a samsung product if they search for XX23 and I want it to show it's an apple product if they search for XX22. Even though in reality it's just one product. Is there any way to do this natively? Will I need an extension? Did I even explain it well enough? Thanks

Maybe this picture helps? https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EzAd.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Catalog` > `Search Terms` and create a synonym for each of the search terms. So...

```
Search query: XX22
Synonym for: ABC123
```

Do the same for `XX23`. Note that this works with the out-of-box Magento search feature, but I'm not sure how it works with any search extension you might have.